# Align labels and corresponding textfields with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I was wondering how can i align labels and corresponding textfields with flexbox.I have tried the fixed width way.But it isnt responsive.
I will attach a image below.In which I tried to align them using a flexbox but didnt work the way I wanted it to :
[image]

PS:The line in between is just a indication for where i want the hyphens(separators) to be aligned.

The HTML code:

```
   <div class="steam-ids">
  <h5 class="mb-5 section-title">STEAM ID'S</h5>
  <div class="profile-overview-steam3-id">
    <label class="name-label">
      <strong>STEAM3ID</strong>
    </label>
    <label class="data-label">
      <span class="separator">-</span>
      <%= dataObj.objSteamIds.steam3id %>
    </label>
    <span class="steam3-copy">
      <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-overview-steam32-id">
    <label class="name-label">
      <strong>STEAMID32</strong>
    </label>
    <label class="data-label">
      <span class="separator">-</span>
      <%= dataObj.objSteamIds.steam2id %>
    </label>
    <span class="steam32-copy">
      <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-overview-steam64-id">
    <label class="name-label">
      <strong>STEAMID64</strong>
    </label>
    <label class="data-label">
      <span class="separator">-</span>
      <a href="<%= dataObj.objSteamIds.steam64 %>">
        <%= dataObj.objSteamIds.steam64 %>
      </a>
    </label>
    <span class="steam64-copy">
      <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <% if(dataObj.objSteamIds.customURL){ %>
    <div class="profile-overview-customURL">
      <label class="name-label">
        <strong>CUSTOM URL</strong>
      </label>
      <label class="data-label">
        <span class="separator">-</span>
        <a href="<%= dataObj.objSteamIds.customURL %>">
          <%= dataObj.objSteamIds.customURL %>
        </a>
      </label>
      <span class="customURL-copy">
        <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

I know that is a lot of HTML.There is a wrapper around the elements inside the container which has a class of "steam-ids".Inside that there are separate "div" for every element.For example.'steam3id' has a div which has a label and a corresponding textfield with a class of "profile-overview-steam3id".

This is the CSS for what I have tried doing:

```
.steam-ids div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Im pretty new to CSS Im learning any help with how can I align the textfields properly is really appreciated.
I wanted the end result to look like this using flexbox
[image]

Comment: You can't as flexbox cannot equalise widths of elements in separate divs. I suggest you try CSS-Grid or, more logically and *semantically* correct, **use a `table`** since that is clearly what you have here. CSS-Tables would also be an option.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i will try out grid thank you

Comment: Your explanations and last image doesn't match.
If you want the hyphens to be exactly at the same spot like you showed on your first image then no flexbox. But if you want it to look like the last image you posted you can perfectly do that with Flexbox. (the hyphens are not aligned, they are at the same distance from their label text)

Comment: ya last one is a bit off..any way i did with grid